# Observable.forkJoin with a for loop

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, angular2-observables

I am trying to populate an array in my component called `processes` which is an array of `process`. Each `process` also has a list of `tasks`.

So currently, I am working with two api calls which are:

`/processes` 
and
`/process/{processId}/tasks`

I use `/processes` to get all the processes and initially populate the `processes` array. Then I use the process id of each `process` to call the second API to get the tasks of that process.

Currently, my code looks something like this:

```
this.processes.forEach((process, index) => {
    myService.getTasks().subscribe((tasks) => {
        process.tasks = tasks;
    })
})
```

I understand that I can create an array of observables, and use `Observable.forkJoin()` to wait for all these async calls to finish but I want to be able to define the subscribe callback function for each of the calls since I need a reference to the `process`. Any ideas on how I can go about approaching this issue?

Comment: Observable.forkJoin will return an array of tasks that match the index of each process in your processes array

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using the `for` loop to make multiple HTTP requests, and then subscribe to all of them separately should be avoided in order not to have many `Observable` connections opened.

As @Juan Mendes mentioned, `Observable.forkJoin` will return an array of tasks that match the index of each process in your processes array. You can also assign tasks to each process as they arrive as follows:

```
getTasksForEachProcess(): Observable<any> {

    let tasksObservables = this.processes.map((process, processIdx) => {
        return myService.getTasks(process)
            .map(tasks => {
                this.processes[processIdx].tasks = tasks; // assign tasks to each process as they arrive
                return tasks;
             })
            .catch((error: any) => {
                console.error('Error loading tasks for process: ' + process, 'Error: ', error);
                return Observable.of(null); // In case error occurs, we need to return Observable, so the stream can continue
            });
    });

    return Observable.forkJoin(tasksObservables);
};

this.getTasksForEachProcess().subscribe(
    tasksArray => {
        console.log(tasksArray); // [[Task], [Task], [Task]];
        // In case error occurred e.g. for the process at position 1,
        // Output will be: [[Task], null, [Task]];

        // If you want to assign tasks to each process after all calls are finished:
        tasksArray.forEach((tasks, i) => this.processes[i].tasks = tasksArray[i]);
    }
);
```

Please also take a look at this post: [Send multiple asynchronous HTTP GET requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619312/send-multiple-asynchronous-http-get-requests/41620361#41620361)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Seid Mehmedovic for great explanation but it looks like code missing one round bracket near map. For me it worked as follows:

```
getTasksForEachProcess(): Observable<any> {

    let tasksObservables = this.processes.map((process, processIdx) => {
        return myService.getTasks(process)
            .map(tasks => {
                this.processes[processIdx].tasks = tasks; // assign tasks to each process as they arrive
                return tasks;
             })
            .catch((error: any) => {
                console.error('Error loading tasks for process: ' + process, 'Error: ', error);
                return Observable.of(null); // In case error occurs, we need to return Observable, so the stream can continue
            });
    });

    return Observable.forkJoin(tasksObservables);
};

this.getTasksForEachProcess().subscribe(
    tasksArray => {
        console.log(tasksArray); // [[Task], [Task], [Task]];
        // In case error occurred e.g. for the process at position 1,
        // Output will be: [[Task], null, [Task]];

        // If you want to assign tasks to each process after all calls are finished:
        tasksArray.forEach((tasks, i) => this.processes[i].tasks = tasksArray[i]);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added the missing bracket.. not sure how it slipped xD