# Loop through/concat list of http observables using Typescript

Tags: angular, loops, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a list of properties that need to be submitted as part of a larger mergeMap operation.

```
this.customFeedsService.postNewSocialMediaFeed(this.newFeed)
            .mergeMap( newFeed => this.customFeedsService.postFeedProperties( newFeed.Id, this.feedProps))
            .mergeMap(newProps => this.customFeedsService.preloadSocialMediaFeed(newProps.FeedId))
            .subscribe(data => console.log(data), err => console.log);
```

In my service is where i loop through the properties to create a single Observable that returns to the mergeMap operation.

```
public postFeedProperties( feedId: number, props: FeedPropertyApi[] ): Observable<any> {
    let observeGroup = new Observable<any>();
    for(let prop of props){
        prop.FeedId = feedId;
        observeGroup.concat(this.apiService.postData(this.feedPropertyApiUrl, prop, true)
            .map(res => res.json()));
    }

    return observeGroup
    // return this.apiService.postData(this.feedPropertyApiUrl, props[0], true)
    //          .map(res => res.json()).concat(this.apiService.postData(this.feedPropertyApiUrl, props[1],true)
    //          .map(res => res.json())).concat(this.apiService.postData(this.feedPropertyApiUrl, props[2], true)
    //          .map(res => res.json()));
}
```

Now when I run the commented portion, everything works as intended. However, when I run through the loop, I get a `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` error. What am I doing wrong in the loop?

Comment: Make an array of Observable with all your Observables. Use Observable.forkJoin(yourArrayObservables).subscribe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42334469/observable-forkjoin-with-a-for-loop?rq=1

Comment: This worked great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the keyword 'as' instead of 'of' in your for loop

```
for(let prop as props) {...}
```

Otherwise could you give more description of where the code is breaking and does it break on the first iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Eliseo for the answer. Here's how I implemented the code.

```
let observeGroup: Observable<any>[] = [];
    for(let prop of props){
        prop.FeedId = feedId;
        observeGroup.push(this.apiService.postData(this.feedPropertyApiUrl, 
        prop, true)
            .map(res => res.json()));
    }
return Observable.forkJoin(observeGroup).map(res => res);
```