# How can I combine two data stores in angular?

Tags: angular

I have this service that gets a list of objects from a django rest api.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Headers, Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';
import {Delegation} from "../delegations/delegation";

@Injectable()
export class DelegationsService {

  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getDelegations(userid: number)  {
    return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + '/api/v1/delegations/' + userid )
      .map(res => <Delegation[]>res.json());
  }
}
```

The contents of `../delegations/delegation.ts` is:

```
export class Delegation {
  id: number;
  delegator: number;
  delegatee: number;
}
```

The numbers for the delegator and delegatee are the database id for "Users".  I need to display the actual users' names and login ids which are available via another REST API url.  I thought I could modify the `../delegations/delegation.ts` to be something like this:

```
export class Delegation {
  id: number;
  delegator: number;
  delegator_login: string;
  delegator_name: string;
  delegatee: number;
  delegatee_login: string;
  delegatee_name: string;
}
```

Then I would iterate over elements I get from `this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + '/api/v1/delegations/' + userid )` call and make a request for the user info, but I have no clue how to do iterate of the result set.

UPDATE:

Currently I can dump the delegator data to my delegations.component.html template and web page displays:

```
2 | 97597 | 5197 
4 | 97597 | 9757
```

What I want to display is:

```
2 | Sam Smith (ssmith) | Lisa Butts (lbutts) 
4 | Sam Smith (ssmith) | Bill Fatlips (bfatlips)
```

My `delegations.component.html` is very simple:

```
<ul class="delegations">
  <li *ngFor="let delegation of delegations" [class.selected]="delegation === selectedDelegation" (click)="onSelect(delegation)">
    <span class="badge">{{delegation.id}}</span> | {{delegation.delegator}} | {{delegation.delegatee}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

It is pretty much what they have in the Heroes Angular tut: https://angular.io/tutorial/

Comment: so basically you need to display the data which you are getting from API?

Comment: Well the data I get is just database record id's.  I need to take those id's are look up the actual user names instead of just the id of their db record.

Comment: I am sorry i not getting you what do mean by ". I need to take those id's are look up the actual user names instead of just the id of their db record."

Comment: I am sorry.  I will update my question to make it more clear what I am trying to do.

Comment: can you post your HTML file as well.

Comment: sure. updated my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165105/discussion-between-hrishikesh-kale-and-red-cricket).

Comment: Create an array of Observables and use forkJoin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42334469/observable-forkjoin-with-a-for-loop?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
getDelegations(userid: number)  {
    return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + '/api/v1/delegations/' + userid )
      .map(res => {
        const theList = <any[]>res.json();
        theList.forEach(item => {
          this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + '/api/v1/delegaor/' + item.delegator)
              .map(res2 => {
                const delegator = res2.json();
                item.delegator_login = delegator.login;
                item.delegator_name = delegator.name;
              });
          this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + '/api/v1/delegatee/' + item.delegatee)
              .map(res3 => {
                const delegatee = res3.json();
                item.delegatee_login = delegatee.login;
                item.delegatee_name = delegatee.name;
              })
        })
        return theList;
      } )
      .subscribe(finalList => {
        // this finalList is your delation list with names and logins and ids
      });
  }
```

I'm a little worried that finalList will be returned before the inner api calls are made, but I think the subscribe will wait for it all to finish up before it is returned. This solution of course is assuming you add the strings to your delegation class.

Comment: nice! But I have been able to convince the back end developers make a change so that I will get all the info I need to display in my initial API request.  They were concerned with performance issues related to the potential numerous API requests.

Comment: That'd be the best solution, getting it all returned from the original call. Wasn't sure if you were consuming an API that you had no control over