# Call Observable.subscribe() in sequence

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an array of object and I want to loop over the array and call the service for each element, **BUT** for every element, I want to call the next element only when the current call is done with success, unless block the rest.

```
    onUpload(items: MyItem[]) {
      items.forEach(i => {
        myService.doSomething(i).subscribe(response => {
          // do something with the success item i
          // do the next call for the next item 
        }, error => {
          // handle the error
        })
      })

     }
```

Is there to call Observables in sequence mode not parallel?

Comment: Maybe this will help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42334469/observable-forkjoin-with-a-for-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `from` to emit values from an array and then `contactMap` to [sequentially execute observables](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap)

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

onUpload(items: MyItem[]) {
  from(items)
    .pipe(
       concatMap(item => myService.doSomething(i))
    )
    .subscribe(response => {/* do something with response */});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `concat` from `rxjs`. Documentation is here https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat.

Code looks like:

```
onUpload(items: MyItem[]) {
  const observableArray = items.map(i => myService.doSomething(i));
  concat(...observableArray).subscribe(
    () => { /* Some logic */ },
    (err) => { /* Some logic */ },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will more gracefull

```
onUpload(items: MyItem[]) {
  from(items)
  .pipe(mergeMap((item) => myService.doSomething(item)))
  .subscribe(
    () => console.log(finish),
    (err) => console.log('error happens', err),
  );
}
```