# Ionic 3 Sqlite: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular, sqlite, asynchronous, ionic3, angular-promise

I have problem while using and retrieving data from sqlite with Ionic and Angular.
Actually I know where the problem appears but not how to solve that in this case.
I'm pretty knew to this and didn't found a solution for that yet (I search since 2 days...).

in my DB Provider I want to fill a List via sql query. The problem is it is async.

Here you can see the code. The problem happens right after eintrag in getPlants.

```
  //Get all Plants
    getPlants() {
      return this.database.executeSql("SELECT * FROM plants", []).then((data) => {
        if (data.rows.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
            this.plants.push({
            plantId: data.rows.item(i).plantId,
            fk_categoriesId: data.rows.item(i).fk_categoriesId,
            name: data.rows.item(i).name,
            favourite : data.rows.item(i).favourite,
            foto: data.rows.item(i).foto,
            aussaatzeitpunkt: data.rows.item(i).aussaatzeitpunkt,
            medium: data.rows.item(i).medium,
            umgebung: data.rows.item(i).umgebung,
            anbauflaeche: data.rows.item(i).anbauflaeche,

         eintrag: this.getOneEntry(data.rows.item(i).plantId).then((d:Tagebucheintraege[])=>{
              console.log("eintrag einer pflanze"+d[0].notiz);
              return d;
            })
           });
          }
        }
        return this.plants;
      }, err => {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
        return [];
      });
    }

    //Get Entry to Plant ID
    getOneEntry(id:number){
        return this.database.executeSql("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE fk_plantId="+id, []).then((data) => {
        if (data.rows.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
            this.entries.push({
            eintragId: data.rows.item(i).eintragId,
            fk_plantId: data.rows.item(i).fk_plantId,
            datum: data.rows.item(i).datum,
            notiz: data.rows.item(i).notiz,
            groesePflanze: data.rows.item(i).groesePflanze,
            phWert: data.rows.item(i).phWert,
            luftfeuchttigkeit: data.rows.item(i).luftfeuchttigkeit,
            erdfeuchtigkeit: data.rows.item(i).erdfeuchtigkeit,
            ecWert: data.rows.item(i).ecWert,
            temperatur: data.rows.item(i).temperatur,
            schaedlinge: data.rows.item(i).schaedlinge,
            mangelerscheinung: data.rows.item(i).eintragId,
            fotopfad: data.rows.item(i).fotopfad,
            beleuchtunngstaerke: data.rows.item(i).beleuchtunngstaerke,
            beleuchtungsabstand: data.rows.item(i).beleuchtungsabstand,
            groeseToepfe: data.rows.item(i).groeseToepfe,
            mengeWasserProTag: data.rows.item(i).MengeWasserProTag,
            artDuengerUndWerteproTag: data.rows.item(i).artDuengerUndWerteproTag,
            mengeduenger: data.rows.item(i).mengeduenger,
            tagVegi: data.rows.item(i).tagVegi,
            tagFlo: data.rows.item(i).tagFlo,
            tagFru: data.rows.item(i).tagFru,
           });
          }
        }
        return this.entries;
      }, err => {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
        return [];
      })
    }
```

The log console.log("eintrag einer pflanze"+d[0].notiz); 
works just fine but I Think eintrag is not yet filled when the plants are returned.
Maybe it will work with Oberservables but I don't know how to use it yet and espacially in this case.
Thank you for your answers!
[Try to access the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHrLq.jpg),
[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRtYz.jpg)

Comment: Yes, you are returning plants before anything has been filled to it, you should add it inside the callback (`then`) after your for-loop, same for the other request.

Comment: and as for perhaps doing this a bit "nicer", you'd maybe want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42829674/7741865 as you mentioned about perhaps using observables in your question :)

Comment: I will check your Link. But plants ist filled ;) Just eintrag is not...